# Why can not get parameter?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I use `v-bind` pass `userId` from Vue instance to it's child component. template :data-user-id can get this value, but in
edit() method, can not ,Why?

### html

```
<aa :userId="userId"></aa>
```

### javascript

```
var aComponent = {
    template: '<a href="#" :data-user-id="userId" @click.prevent="edit()">click me</a>',
    props: ['userId'],
    methods: {
        edit: function () {
            console.log('edit user:' + this.id + ":" + this.userId);
        }
    },
    data: function(){
        return {
            id: this.userId
        };
    }
};
var vm = new Vue({
    data: function () {
        return {

            userId: '201'
        };
    },
    components: {
        aa: aComponent
    },
    el: '#app'
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attribute needs to be [kebab-case](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#camelCase-vs-kebab-case).

> HTML attributes are case-insensitive, so when using non-string
> templates, camelCased prop names need to use their kebab-case
> (hyphen-delimited) equivalents

```
<aa :user-id="userId"></aa>
```